# How to set color for BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android

I need to use android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground", but so that the day and night versions have different values. How can I do this? Is it possible to do this with using colors.xml and themes.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** of all define **night-value** folder and **night** **theme** in appropriate resource directory.

**res/values-night/themes.xml**

**Override** `android:windowBackground` like this :

```
  <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/screen_night</item>
    </style>
```

Then you can customize your screen like this :

**res/drawable/screen_night.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/white"/>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@drawable/any_logo"
       android:tileMode="disabled"/>
</item>
```